# Using render in RSpec view test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm using RSpec to test my views. I want to test that the view for the `edit` action contains a field (or text) "Director". It's choking on `render`. Here's my code:

```
# spec/views/movies/edit.html.haml_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'movies/edit.html.haml' do
  it 'displays \'director\' field on edit page' do
    render
    expect(rendered).to have_content("Director")
  end
end
```

On running this I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: render
ActionView::Template::Error:
  No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"movies", :id=>nil}
```

My understanding is that convention over configuration means that `render` without any arguments should render the intended view `app/views/movies/edit.html.haml` I don't know why it's looking for the route to the action `show`. That route does exist, though it has nothing to do with this spec.

I've tried a number of permuations of arguments to `render` with no luck:

```
render :edit
render action: :edit # is this even valid?
render :action => :edit
render "edit"
render "edit.html.haml"
render action: "edit"
render action: "edit.html.haml"
render :action => "edit"
render :action => "edit.html.haml"
```

All the above produce one of two errors:

```
ArgumentError:
  You invoked render but did not give any of :partial, :template, :inline, :file or :text option.
```

OR

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate:
  Missing partial /edit, movies/edit with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}.
```

I'm not trying to render a partial, I'm trying to render the full view. Am I using the convention incorrectly, or using `render` incorrectly?

**Edit1**: I don't **think** it's a partial. There is a view at `app/views/movies/edit.html.haml`. I may not properly understand what a partial is.

**Edit2**: I tried the same spec for the `new` action and it seems to run fine (fails when the text is not there, passes when the text is there). Does this mean I need to load the `edit` view as a partial, or do I need to give it dummy data for `@movie`? And why is `edit` a partial?

Comment: It's more likely that in your actual edit view, you are making a link to the show page of a `movie` object, but that object is nil, and so the page cannot be rendered and gives you that error. Look to see if you're doing `link_to movie` or `link_to @movie` or `form_for @movie`, or some variation, anywhere.

Comment: I do have `form_tag movie_path(@movie)` in the view. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. You do not set up that variable anywhere, so when Rails is rendering that path, it fails because it knows that path is bogus. In your test just do `@movie = X`, and either create a new movie or set up a fake one that has an ID attribute that's non-nil. Also, your view isn't a partial. I think the only reason why you think it is is because of the default text in the ActionView::MissingTemplate error. Don't worry about that. You know it's not a partial.

Comment: No problem. If you want I can put all that down as an answer for you to accept.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking for something similar, you should be assigning a movie model for the view to render.

Something like the following should work:

```
describe 'movies/edit.html.haml' do
  let(:movie) { Movie.create(movie_params_go_here) }

  it 'displays \'director\' field on edit page' do
    assign(:movie, movie)
    render
    expect(rendered).to have_content("Director")
  end
end
```